# Can a compound functions of multi-valued functions result in a single-valued function?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivalued-functions

For example, $f_1(z)$ and $f_2(z)$ are some multi-valued functions. Is it possible for there to exists a single-valued function $f(z)$ such that$$f(z) = f_1(f_2(z))$$
If so can you please give an example?

Comment: I don't know if I understood your question correctly: when you say multi-valued you mean a function taking values on a cartesian product, say, $\mathbb{C}^{n}$? If so, this is not possible. Note that $f$ is just $f_{1}$ evaluated at $f_{2}(z)$ so you'd need $f_{2}(z)$ do be an element of the domain of $f_{1}$ and, since $f_{1}$ is multi-valued, $f_{1}(f_{2}(z)) \equiv f_{1}(\bar{z})$ is not single-valued.

Comment: @IamWill Not cartesian product, that's multi-variable functions I think. Multi-valued functions are complex functions that use the complex plane as its domain. For example, using the polar form $z = re^{i\theta + 2k\pi}, k \in Z$, we can see that $w = \sqrt{z} = r^{1/2}e^{i(\theta /2 + k\pi)}, k \in Z$, with different $k$s we can get different $w$s. (i.e. we get more than one result from the function with a single input)

Comment: @IamWill The notion of "multivalued function" is quite standard in complex analysis. The canonical example would be the logarithm.

Comment: $\exp(\log(z))=z$

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich thanks for the comments. I think I got confused with the term multi-variable" instead of "multivalued".